# Elasticity Panel Data

Tags: r, panel-data, elasticity

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

Fileds

1. `Profit x Product`: It is the variable that I can change, and is the independent variable.
2. `%Sales`: Number of sales/Customer
3. `%Sales With subscription`: Number of Sales with subscription/ Sales

Question:

1. I would like to make a model that captures the relation between
   `%Sales` and `%Sales with Subscription`, such that

$$ Y_2 + Y_1 = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 X_1 + \epsilon $$

- $Y_1$ = `%Sales with Subscription`
- $Y_2$ = `%Sales`
- $X_1$ = `Profit x Product`

What kind of model I can use?

2. After obtaining the model, I would like to calculate the elasticity of the `Profit x Product` by `group`, like this.

[image]

[image]

How can make this analysis of elasticity?

I would like to make this analysis in `R`.

Comment: Please explain what $Y_1$, $Y_2$, and $X_2$ are in question 1 (i.e. which one is %Sales etc)

Comment: @Lynn Thanks, done!!!

Comment: I am confused as to why you add $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ in the model. Do you want to estimate elasticities for their sum? Or do I understand it correctly that you want to estimate elasticities with respect to each of them individually?

Comment: Hi, @MartinGeorgHaas  I want to estimate the sales and of these sales the sales with the subscription. For this, I would like to be together.

Answer (score 0):

##### What kind of model I can use?

You can use a log-log model, to estimate elasticities:
$$
\log(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \log(X) + \dots + \varepsilon
$$
Just set $Y$ to your desired outcome variable (e.g. `%Sales`) and $X$ to `Profit x Product`. The coefficient $\beta_i$ then gives the ([ceteris paribus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus)) percentage change in $Y$ given a $1\%$ change in $X$.

##### Individual elasticities per group

If you want to estimate individual elasticities for each group you can add an interaction effect:
$$
\log(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \log(X)\times group + \dots + \varepsilon
$$
where $group$ is a dummy variable indicating the group membership.

##### `R` implementation

You can estimate this model via:

```
lm(log(Y) ~ log(X):group,
   data = data)
```

Comment: Why do you use log-log model and not something like panel data? or multilevel model?

Comment: The log-log functional form or the model allows you to interpret $\beta_1$ as elasticity. It does not prevent you from using panel data or other methods.

Comment: Hi @Martin, but I think that with this approach I miss the relation between groups

Comment: What relation between groups are you trying to model? Please be more specific.

Comment: Hi, As panel data, you can use the random effect to model de effect across all the groups, with this approach we are not capturing this relation.